# Finding the phone numbers in 50,000 HTML pages

Tags: regex, algorithm, language-agnostic

### How do you find the phone numbers in 50,000 HTML pages?

> #### Jeff Attwood posted 5 Questions for programmers applying for jobs:
>
> In an effort to make life simpler for phone screeners, I've put together
>   this list of Five Essential Questions
>   that you need to ask during an SDE
>   screen. They won't guarantee that your
>   candidate will be great, but they will
>   help eliminate a huge number of
>   candidates who are slipping through
>   our process today.
>
> **1) Coding** The candidate has to write
>   some simple code, with correct syntax,
>   in C, C++, or Java.
>
> **2) OO design** The candidate has to
>   define basic OO concepts, and come up
>   with classes to model a simple
>   problem.
>
> **3) Scripting and regexes** The
>   candidate has to describe how to find
>   the phone numbers in 50,000 HTML
>   pages.
>
> **4) Data structures** The candidate has
>   to demonstrate basic knowledge of the
>   most common data structures.
>
> **5) Bits and bytes** The candidate has
>   to answer simple questions about bits,
>   bytes, and binary numbers.
>
> Please understand: what I'm looking
>   for here is a total vacuum in one of
>   these areas. It's OK if they struggle
>   a little and then figure it out. It's
>   OK if they need some minor hints or
>   prompting. I don't mind if they're
>   rusty or slow. What you're looking for
>   is candidates who are utterly
>   clueless, or horribly confused, about
>   the area in question.
>
> **[>>> The Entirety of Jeff´s Original Post <<<](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001042.html)**

**Note:** Steve Yegge originally posed the Question.

Comment: I keep trying to figure out how you can "write code" in a phone interview... but it's just not coming to me.......

Comment: The operative term is "describe". You may have an excellent implementation in mind, but you are really being assessed on you ability to impart that concept to someone else verbally.

Comment: So why say 50,000 web pages? Why not just say how do you find the phone number in a web page. Then that makes more sense. To say 50,000 is that just something to throw the person off?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
egrep "(([0-9]{1,2}.)?[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4})" . -R --include='*.html'
```

Comment: According to http://countrycode.org/ some codes have 3 or even 4 digits! Are we limiting this regex to only the popular countries?

Comment: Fantastic answer, although this does not catch phone number strings that have no dashes or spaces between them.  (i.e. it would not catch `1234567890`, as it expects something like `123-456-7890`).  To solve this, you can simply add a `{0,1}` to each of the `.`.  It would look like: `(([0-9]{1,2}.)?[0-9]{3}.{0,1}[0-9]{3}.{0,1}[0-9]{4})`

Answer (score 3):

Made this in Java. The regex was borrowed from [this forum](http://forums.msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/regexp/thread/8d4846c0-4eca-427a-b34a-856c7f8695cb/).

```
    final String regex = "[\\s](\\({0,1}\\d{3}\\){0,1}" +
            "[- \\.]\\d{3}[- \\.]\\d{4})|" +
            "(\\+\\d{2}-\\d{2,4}-\\d{3,4}-\\d{3,4})";
    final Pattern phonePattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    
    /* The result set */
    Set<File> files = new HashSet<File>();
    
    File dir = new File("/initDirPath");
    if (!dir.isDirectory()) return;
    
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) continue;
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        
        String line;
        boolean found = false;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null 
                && !found) {
            
            if (found = phonePattern.matcher(line).find()) {
                files.add(file);
            }
        }
    }

    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Performed some tests and it went ok! :)
Remeber I'm not trying to use the best design here. Just implemented the algorithm for that.

Comment: Seems to me like this only lists files that have phone numbers; it doesn't actually extract and list the actual numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a improved regex pattern

```
\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s\.]?\d{3}[-\s\.]?\d{4}
```

It is able to identify several number formats

1. xxx.xxx.xxxx
2. xxx.xxxxxxx
3. xxx-xxx-xxx
4. xxxxxxxxxx
5. (xxx) xxx xxxx
6. (xxx) xxx-xxxx
7. (xxx)xxx-xxxx

Comment: The pattern number 3 in your example, does not appear to be matched by your regex using grep. It also required that I use the -P (for perl compatible regex) in order for grep to work with this regex pattern. You can fix it with: \(?\d{3}\)?[-\s\.]?\d{3}[-\s\.]?\d{3,4} (c.f the ending {3,4})

Answer (score 2):

```
egrep '\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s.]?\d{3}[-.]\d{4}' *.html
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing 2 things from the C# answer from sieben, here's a little F# snippet that will do the job. All it's missing is a way to call processDirectory, which is left out intentionally :)

```
open System
open System.IO
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

let rgx = Regex(@"(\({0,1}\d{3}\){0,1}[- \.]\d{3}[- \.]\d{4})|(\+\d{2}-\d{2,4}-\d{3,4}-\d{3,4})", RegexOptions.Compiled)

let processFile contents = contents |> rgx.Matches |> Seq.cast |> Seq.map(fun m -> m.Value)

let processDirectory path = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.html", SearchOption.AllDirectories) |> Seq.map(File.ReadAllText >> processFile) |> Seq.concat
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl Solution

By: "MH" via codinghorror,com on September 5, 2008 07:29 AM

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<*.html>) {
    my $filename = $_;
    my @data     = <$filename>;

    # Loop once through with simple search
    while (@data) {
        if (/\(?(\d\d\d)\)?[ -]?(\d\d\d)-?(\d\d\d\d)/) {
            push( @files, $filename );
            next;
        }
    }

    # None found, strip html
    $text = "";
    $text .= $_ while (@data);
    $text =~ s#<[^>]+>##gxs;

    # Strip line breaks
    $text =~ s#\n|\r##gxs;

    # Check for occurrence.
    if ( $text =~ /\(?(\d\d\d)\)?[ -]?(\d\d\d)-?(\d\d\d\d)/ ) {
        push( @files, $filename );
        next;
    }
}

# Print out result
print join( '\n', @files );
```

Answer (score 1):

i love doing these little problems, can't help myself.

not sure if it was worth doing though since it's very similar to the java answer.

```
private readonly Regex phoneNumExp = new Regex(@"(\({0,1}\d{3}\){0,1}[- \.]\d{3}[- \.]\d{4})|(\+\d{2}-\d{2,4}-\d{3,4}-\d{3,4})");

public HashSet<string> Search(string dir)
{
    var numbers = new HashSet<string>();

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.html", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var match = phoneNumExp.Match(line);

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    numbers.Add(match.Value);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return numbers;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's why phone interview coding questions don't work:

phone screener: how do you find the phone numbers in 50,000 HTML pages?

candidate: hang on one second (covers phone) hey (roommate/friend/etc who's super good at programming), how do you find the phone numbers in 50,000 HTML pages?

Save the coding questions for early in the in-person interview, and make the interview questions more personal, i.e. "I'd like details about the last time you solved a problem using code".  That's a question that will beg follow-ups to their details and it's a lot harder to get someone else to answer it for you without sounding weird over the phone.

Comment: You are correct, some people will plan on cheating during a phone screen but many will not, whether because of a love of the truth, fear of being caught, lack of knowledgeable co-conspirators, general inconvenience. Anyone in this group that can't answer the question will be effectively screened. Since the goal isn't to confirm coding expertise during the phone call, but rather to save time by reducing wasted interview, I would consider it a big mistake to not ask technical questions in a phone conversation.